# iPhone Open DATA: Url In Safari

Tags: iphone, url, safari, data-url

I have a Data: URL (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (as a NSString) and I want to open it in Safari. How would you accomplish this (I tried openURL:.)
Example:

```
data:text/html;base64,(Some Base64 Encoded Data Here)
```

Comment: openURL should work (that is what it is intended for!) what happened when you tried using openURL?

Comment: it might help to show the URL. Maybe it is badly formed.

Comment: I have actually seen this work... can't get it to work myself ATM but trying...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In iPhone OS 2.2.1 and 5.0.1, in both the simulator and on a device, opening a **data:** url works perfectly in a `UIWebView` but using `openURL` does precisely nothing.

And Safari will gladly, and properly, render such an URL if you are willing to type one into the navigation bar, so this is clearly a problem with `sharedApplication openURL`, not with Safari.

If the base64 string is short enough (less than 2K, probably) you could wrap it as a query parameter to an http URL that simply returns a redirect to the data url.  Then you could use openURL to open the http URL.  Yes, this means bouncing through some server, but it would work.

Alternatively, since Safari obviously hasn't done it, you *could* tell the iPhone that *your* app is the handler for the **data:** scheme and take responsibility for rendering the content in a UIWebView.  This seems likely to fail in the future, though.  :-)

Where is the data URL coming from in the first place?  Perhaps you could construct a web page whose contents are nothing more than `<iframe src="<the data url>"/>` and again, use openURL on that URL.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
NSURL *yourURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:yourStr];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:yourURL];
[yourURL release];
```

assuming "yourStr" is an NString with the URL where your data is located.

Comment: A way to get around that might be to just display it in a UIWebView object. That's basically Safari, but entirely within your own app.

Comment: I need the user to be able to bookmark the page - so Safari is the only option.