# iphone configuration profile installed via webkit

Tags: iphone, configuration, safari, webkit, profile

Good day!

I am using Xcode 3.1.4 and iPhone SDK 2.2.1. I am creating an iphone application and i would need the user to download a custom configuration profile (created by me) from a URL loaded via webkit. I have tested the URL in safari and it downloads and installs the profile just fine. however, the url opened via webkit could NOT download it. Why is this happening? Is this really possible?

any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You application runs in a sandbox and has different permissions that Mobile Safari.  Only Safari has permission to install the configuration, so you must pass the url to it.

Comment: thought so, thanks drawnforward for a quick reply. i needed that assurance that it can't be done. however, would there be, by any chance, any hacks to get that same permission as safari to install a config?