# How can you create a link wrapped into an app Icon?

Tags: iphone, redirect, icons

I've seen a lot of apps that can create icons for on the home screen. You add it through the normal Add on Home Screeen and when you click on the app it will directly start calling or whatever. This must be done by immediately redirecting to an url like sms:// or tel:// depending on what you are trying to do. But how is this accomplished?

How can you let a page be bookmarked normally so it will get the icon and then when it's pressed immediately redirect it to a specific url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK, these icons are made using Configuration Profiles & application links (url schemes).
Have a look at this thread: [Installing a configuration profile on iPhone - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically)

But they didn't find a solution in there. Profiles can only be installed via MobileSafari, they say. Not via a UIWebView. So i'm not sure how it's possible from native apps.

Anyhow the [preference shortcuts](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/11/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-to-wifi-settings-airplane-mode-and-more-no-jailbreak-required/) aren't working anymore on iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as your app is opened, you call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];
```