# iOS - serving configuration profile via UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, safari, uiwebview

My question is: would it be at all possible to avoid the call to Safari so as to install the profile?
I am able to use the localhost server approach described in [Installing a configuration profile on iPhone - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically) to serve it through Safari, but would like to avoid having to call it and then have to re-open the app on confirmation...

I know Safari and Mail are supposed to be the only applications whose permissions allow them to launch those profiles, but since the Mime type is now public ("application/x-apple-aspen-config"), would there be a way to make it work with a UIWebView?

I found several resources talking about this (mostly saying it isn't possible) but most are over 3-4 years old, which makes me wonder if anything might have changed in the meantime, or if Safari and Mail remain as the only web-based "methods" to launching configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not possible yet (15/09/15).
Hopefully this will change in the future...