# ios install the mobileconfig freeze white screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari

I am installing the `.mobileconfig` using the safari.

But, sometimes when I arouse the safari, it will navigation to the install the `mobileconfig` page.

The screen will freeze on the white screen, that does not show the install button on the right top.

like below:

[image]

Have anyone had encounter the same problem?

My code to call the safari is using below code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:777/myconfig.mobileconfig"];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

I had copy the error command log like below:

```
 Jan  7 21:53:25 James-iphone nsurlsessiond[109] <Error>: Task 2 for client <CFString 0x154e5e4f0 [0x1a0e33b68]>{contents = "com.apple.mobileassetd"} completed with error - code: -999
 Jan  7 21:53:25 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
 Jan  7 21:53:25 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Notice>: MIS: Using empty blacklist.
 Jan  7 21:53:25 James-iphone syncdefaultsd[519] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "opportunistic" on <APSConnection: 0x136515d10>
 Jan  7 21:53:26 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
 Jan  7 21:53:26 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Notice>: MIS: Using empty blacklist.
 Jan  7 21:53:26 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Applying iPhone defaults
 Jan  7 21:53:26 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Warning>: BTM: attaching to BTServer
 Jan  7 21:53:26 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
 Jan  7 21:53:26 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Notice>: MIS: Using empty blacklist.
 Jan  7 21:53:27 James-iphone syncdefaultsd[519] <Notice>: (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "enabled" on <APSConnection: 0x136515d10>
 Jan  7 21:53:27 James-iphone MobileSafari[514] <Error>: KeychainGetICDPStatus: keychain: -25300
 Jan  7 21:53:27 James-iphone MobileSafari[514] <Error>: KeychainGetICDPStatus: status: off
 Jan  7 21:53:27 James-iphone MobileSafari[514] <Error>: KeychainGetICDPStatus: keychain: -25300
 Jan  7 21:53:27 James-iphone MobileSafari[514] <Error>: KeychainGetICDPStatus: status: off
 Jan  7 21:53:27 James-iphone MobileSafari[514] <Error>: KeychainGetICDPStatus: keychain: -25300
 Jan  7 21:53:27 James-iphone MobileSafari[514] <Error>: KeychainGetICDPStatus: status: off
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1720
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone Preferences[464] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 5.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (2 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183805900 0x182e73f80 0x1838057d0 0x18417899c 0x1886f004c 0x1941301c4 0x194136d64 0x183259630 0x1832595f0 0x18325ecf8 0x1837bcbb0 0x1837baa18 0x1836e9680 0x184bf8088 0x188560d90 0x1000b7718 0x18328a8b8)
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.Preferences[0xfe24][464]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.Preferences[0xfe24]' crashed.
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 2463897065357: id=com.apple.Preferences pid=464, state=0
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone MobileGestaltHelper[88] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:276: server_access_check denied access to question UniqueDeviceID for pid 519
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone syncdefaultsd[519] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:151: pid 519 (syncdefaultsd) does not have sandbox access for re6Zb+zwFKJNlkQTUeT+/w and IS NOT appropriately entitled
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone syncdefaultsd[519] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:537: no access to UniqueDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone diagnosticd[82] <Error>: unable to find offset 0x8327f9a4 in shared cache for arch 'arm64'
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone ReportCrash[520] <Notice>: platform_thread_get_unique_id matched 240727
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone ReportCrash[520] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[464] Preferences
 Jan  7 21:53:28 James-iphone ReportCrash[520] <Warning>: saved type '109_Preferences' report (21 of max 25) as /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Preferences_2016-01-07-215328_James-iphone.ips
 Jan  7 21:53:29 James-iphone pkd[154] <Warning>: assigning plug-in app.cyan.timy.dayext(2.2) to plugin sandbox
 Jan  7 21:53:29 James-iphone pkd[154] <Warning>: enabling pid=54 for plug-in app.cyan.timy.dayext(2.2) B9580AEF-CE50-4DD3-A98C-9B5AF2933220 /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D753EF69-C9C2-4C71-9755-79F8553787A9/HourDay.app/PlugIns/DayExt.appex
 Jan  7 21:53:30 James-iphone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: plugin app.cyan.timy.dayext invalidated
 Jan  7 21:53:31 James-iphone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
 Jan  7 21:53:31 James-iphone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
 Jan  7 21:53:31 James-iphone com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[518] <Error>: CoreAnimation: failed to allocate IOSurface
 Jan  7 21:53:36 James-iphone mediaserverd[25] <Notice>: '' (pid = 516) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
 Jan  7 21:53:36 James-iphone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.A90CE0BD-CDCB-43AB-9311-B0D990645C4E[516]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
 Jan  7 21:53:36 James-iphone mediaserverd[25] <Notice>: '' (pid = 516) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
 Jan  7 21:53:36 James-iphone mediaserverd[25] <Notice>: 'FigPlayer - 31' (pid = 31) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
 Jan  7 21:53:36 James-iphone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls]      Updating supported commands for now playing application.
```

Maybe can give you some hint.

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing OVER other profiles or along with others? I've replaced mine a few times now and iOS 9.1 doesn't like it for me on the iPhone 6+.

The only (want most painless) way I've found is to remove the old profiles before I install new ones via Xcode

On Xcode:

```
1) Click on the "Window" menu
2) Click on "Devices"
3) Wait for your Device (devices) to load .. Oh make sure they're     plugged in! hah
4) Right click on the device you need to change profiles on
5) Click on "Show provisioning profiles"
```

In there you can add and delete profiles safely :)

**edit**

The other options is what's called OTAC (over the air configuration)... It's exactly what happens when your mobile phone provider sends you new APN settings and it asks you to install the settings "out of the blue"...

The docs are here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html

The only issue you'll have is that this isn't something you can do on the simulator so you'd better create "dummy profiles" to avoid replacing your development or production ones.

Another note, I did find this post on here: [Installing a configuration profile on iPhone - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: Thank for your response at first. But I have some purpose that will replace and install the mobileconfig file by coding. Or have possible using code delete the profiles? And the problems not every time show, sometimes show the problems. But I don't know why.. thanks.

Comment: Ah right, in that case, I'll update my answer again :)

Comment: sorry, Maybe you have misunderstanding my meaning. I already using httpserver open the safari, and almost that can navigation to the profile install page is ok(that have blue text about install in the right top). I am using httpserver(https://github.com/natevw/CouchTalk-iOS/blob/master/CouchTalk/HTTPServer.h) . But sometime the  user to install the profile, the user click button and open url to install. It will show the screen page. Have other methods to solve the problem using openurl, or why have show the white screen, is OS Bug?

Comment: I am using  safari in localhost and install it. But sometime show the white screen.

Comment: No~ :( I just the same profiles. And the profiles can correct run. But when I replace the same profiles(reinstall same profiles, but the setting content not the same) , somtimes it will freeze white let not navigation to install screen truly .