# Installing font using configuration profile in iPhone using Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, configuration, profile

We have a requirement where we want users to be able to install fonts on their iPhone devices through our app itself. Similar like this app :

[AnyFont on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id821560738?mt=8)

We came across this :
[Installing a configuration profile on iPhone - programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically)

But we aren't able to figure out on how to create a configuration profile to install font just the way AnyFont did it.

Comment: Hi Omkar. Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create font certificate using Apple Configurator Utility.below is a link to download this Utility. 
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12

Comment: Hey Nishant ... how do I create font certificate programmatically using Objective - C ?

Comment: you don't need to create it programatically.create mobileconfig  using this utility and put that certificate in your app bundle or on the server from where this certificate will be installed

Comment: Nishant .. You are right ... But look at this video : http://flo.vc/AnyFont
At 2:48 you will see that they are able to install fonts from the app itself.
We want the same functionality to be one of the features of our app which we are building .