# Add wifi list to ios device like in Openroaming app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am working of app which provides connection to different wifi networks. We do it via downloading profiles. We want to do it with as less user interaction as possible.
From Apple documentation there are three methods to do it:

- *Via mdm profiles which requires user to install them in settings*
- *With NEHotspotHelper which is still require user go to settings wifi list*
- *With NEHotspotConfigurationManager where user need to agree to every separate wifi suggested.*

However if you download OpenRoaming app (Cisco) from AppStore and try to use it. It will only once will be prompted with message "OpenRoaming Wants to Add a Wi-Fi Hotspot Network?" and that's it.
So what the way are they using to make such a convenient way for connection to wifi?

Comment: It implements an `NEHotspotHelper` extension https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper

Comment: @Paulw11 - NEHotspotHelper requires from user go to wi-fi settings  and choose wifi from list (wifi which NEHotspotHelper can process will be marked this case) and this method is described in Apple docs BUT OpenRoaming connects to wifi in background without any user interaction. Only single message will be prompted once and for all future connection. No any user interaction needed.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Open roaming adds a hotspot 2.0 configuration to your device via a mobile configuration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes. That was what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! Is there a way to make your comment as answer to this post?